# Records of complex PySpark Dataframe disappear when filter and persist

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

**Input**:

PySpark DF read in from a JSON file (output of previous ETL job) with complex data structure (many nested fields). File contains 100,000+ records.

I need to filter the records which have non-empty field 'name.en'.
Beforehand, I manually checked the contents of input JSON file - fieldc'name.en' is empty for 5% of all records, so I expect to see 95,000 records in output.

**Problem**:

When Spark reads data and persists that in `MEMORY_ONLY` (or `MEMORY_AND_DISK`) most of the records disappear.

- Case #1 - with persist (doesn't work)

  ```py
  df = sparkSession.read.format('json').schema(REQUIRED_SCHEMA).load(JSON_FILE_PATH)
  df.persist(pyspark.StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY)
  print(df.filter('name.en IS NOT NULL').count()) #returns 115 records instead of 95,000+
  ```

explain for df.filter('name.en IS NOT NULL')  with `persist()`:

```py
== Physical Plan ==
Filter (isnotnull(name#2) && isnotnull(name#2.en))
+- InMemoryTableScan [_id#0, field1#1, name#2, ..., field31#31], [isnotnull(name#2), isnotnull(name#2.en)]
     +- InMemoryRelation [_id#0, field1#1, name#2, ..., field31#31], true, 10000, StorageLevel(memory, 1 replicas)
           +- FileScan json [_id#0,field#1,name#2,..., field31#31] Batched: false, Format: JSON, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[file:/data/myfile.json], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<_id:struct<oid:string>,field1:string,name:struct<en:string>,field3:struct<oi...
```

But when I remove persist() call it returns correct number of records.
- Case #2 - Without persist (works as expected)

```py
    df = sparkSession.read.format('json').schema(REQUIRED_SCHEMA).load(JSON_FILE_PATH)
    print(df.filter('name.en IS NOT NULL').count()) #returns 95,000+ records as expected
```

explain for df.filter('name.en IS NOT NULL')  without `persist()`:

```py
== Physical Plan ==
Project [_id#0, field1#1, name#2, ... , field31#31]
+- Filter (isnotnull(name#2) && isnotnull(name#2.en))
  +- FileScan json [_id#0,field1#1,name#2,...,field31#31] Batched: false, Format: JSON, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[file:/data/myfile.json], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(name)], ReadSchema: struct<_id:struct<oid:string>,field1:string,name:struct<en:string>,field3:struct<oi...
```

So the only difference is the presence/absence of `persist()` call.
What might cause such strange results?

Comment: Can you check `df.explain()` and `df.persist().explain()` and post them here.

Comment: See edits in original post

Comment: The plans look fine to me. There's got to be a bug somewhere, could you try and make a minimal example including some data to reproduce this? If we can make reproducible example it'll help us track down the bug.

See if you can reproduce this using just a 100 or so rows of your table.

Which version of spark are you on BTW? Do you have access to another version?